# How to generate fontspec.sty file after downloading fontspec package?

Tags: fontspec, awesome-cv

I am trying to create a CV using a LaTeX template. I am using XeLaTeX in MacTex. I have downloaded and unzipped the required fontspec package from CTAN, and placed it in the folder where other packages are found, but there is no fontspec.sty file in the fontspec folder. With other packages, I have run a .ins file to install the .sty file, but here there is no .ins file either, and I don't see information about installation in the readme or PDF files either. Can someone please explain how to generate a .sty file from this package? As you can see, I am not very TeX savvy, so the simplicity and clarity of your answer is appreciated in advance. Thank you!

Comment: any tex distribution will have fontspec already or have it available by a package update, you should never have to install it from ctan.

Comment: If you installed MacTeX you have the package. Just use `\usepackage{fontspec}` in your document.

Comment: Hmm, my document has \usepackage{fontspec}, which leads to a '! LaTeX Error: File `fontspec.sty' not found' message, which was what prompted me to try to download the package myself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed TeX Live using the MacTeX installer package there should be no need to install fontspec, it's already part of TeX Live. I can't speak for other TeX distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed TeX Live using the MacTeX installer package there should be no need to install fontspec, it's already part of TeX Live. I can't speak for other TeX distributions.

If you want to update a new TeX Live installation use the TeX Live Utility which can be found in /Applications/TeX.

Comment: Thank you. I located the package in TeX Live (indeed installed using MacTeX) and clicked to 'reinstall' the package, but received an error message. The last five messages in the log are 'child process pid = 2453 exited', 'Value of errno is Operation not permitted', '*** ERROR *** exit status of pid = 2453 was 1', 'waitpid returned 2452, WIFEXITED(256) = 1, errno = 0 (No error), and 'kqueue noted that tlu-ipctask (pid = 2452) exited with status 1'.

Comment: Why do you believe it wasn't installed in the first place? Did you just try to use it? If you don't did you manually remove it? What ls version an TeX Live version are you using?

Comment: My recollection is that I first got an error message that fontspec.sty wasn't found, and went to download it. In hindsight I should have looked at what fontspec was more carefully. I have version 1.24 of TeX Live.

Comment: @Alex : I'm not sure I understand what you mean by version 1.24 of TeX Live. TeX Live versions are denoted by the year of release.

Comment: I see. My version is from 2016.

Comment: You can no longer update TeX Live 2016 using TeX Live Utility (or tlmgr directly). You can get MacTeX 2017 from [https://www.tug.org/mactex/](https://www.tug.org/mactex/).

Comment: Aha, installing MacTex 2017 works! I have fontspec.sty again and am able to compile the document I was originally working on. So I guess the lesson is to keep updating. Thank you so much for your help @Herb; this must have seemed like a very trivial case to you.